# Scanning into an Array

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, eof

I'm trying to scan in a file containing x amount of doubles into two separate arrays, where which array the double is scanned in to alternates one after the other. Everything is working pretty well, but I keep scanning in a 0 into an extra element in both my arrays (not part of my list of doubles from the file).

If I were to scan in enough doubles that both arrays had 37 elements with doubles, my code makes it so I have 38 elements, with a zero in the last element for both arrays.

ARR_SIZE is 1500

```
Size read_array(double array1[], double array2[])
{
    Size size = {0, 0};

    int i = 0;

    int status1 = 0;
    int status2 = 0;

    status1 = scanf("%lf", &array1[i]);
    size.sigSize1++;

    status2 = scanf("%lf", &array2[i]);
    size.sigSize2++;

    while(size.sigSize1 < ARR_SIZE && size.sigSize2 < ARR_SIZE && 
         (status1 != EOF || status2 != EOF))
    {
        i++;

        status1 = scanf("%lf", &array1[i]);
        size.sigSize1++;


        status2 = scanf("%lf", &array2[i]);
        size.sigSize2++;


    }

    return size;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incrementing the sizes too early: you should guard the `++` with the check of `statusX != EOF`, like this:

```
status1 = scanf("%lf", &array1[i]);
if (status1 != EOF) {
    size.sigSize1++;
}

status2 = scanf("%lf", &array2[i]);
if (status2 != EOF) {
    size.sigSize2++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So scanf reads from keyboard input. You don't want to be typing, I assume.

You want to use fscanf to read from a FILE pointer, after you use fopen to open the file for reading.